# In C# unity my wait function is not waiting correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have recently learned coroutines in C# unity and I tried creating a wait function to wait in between codes. It prints both statements at the same time instead of waiting three seconds. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Learninghowtoprogram : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        print("hello"); 
        wait(3);
        print("hello2");      
    }

    IEnumerator waito(float time)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);        
    }

    void wait(float time)
    {
        StartCoroutine(waito(time));     
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because `Start` is not the function doing any waiting, it is `waito` that is waiting.  Put your 2 logs at the beginning and end of `waito` and you will see the delay works correctly.

Comment: You can get `Start` to have a delay by changing the return type to `IEnumerator` and replacing `wait(3);` with `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is when `Start()` gets called it tries to execute each line one by one

```
print("hello"); 
wait(3);
print("hello2");
```

So when you are calling the `wait(3)` it goes in it's own scope and calls the **waito** Coroutine.

Now see the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);` is doing it's job correctly that means it's waiting for 3 seconds but in it's scope (inside itself) so what you can do is move `print("hello");` and `print("hello2");` in the Coroutine itself like this..

```
public class Learninghowtoprogram : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        wait(3);
    }

    void wait(float time)
    {
        StartCoroutine(waito(time));
    }

    IEnumerator waito(float time)
    {
        print("hello");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        print("hello2");
    }
}
```

Or, you can remove `wait()` and directly start the Coroutine like this also

```
public class Learninghowtoprogram : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(waito(3));
    }

    IEnumerator waito(float time)
    {
        print("hello");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        print("hello2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you to stop time in function or wait to perform a task. Use [Async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

```cs
private async void Start()
{
    print("hello");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    print("hello2");
}
```

Comment: does that work in a Unity context? I would expect you need an `IEnumerator` and `yield`

Comment: @KYL3R Of course it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Start` a Coroutine by returning IEnumerator.

```
private IEnumerator Start() {
    Debug.Log("Start 1");
    yield return waito(3);
    Debug.Log("Start 2");
}
IEnumerator waito(float time) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
}
```

Note the Timestamps:

[image: Logs from delayed Start]

But I think it's bad design. `Awake` is called before `Start`, `Start` is called before the first `Update`. And sometimes Unity devs rely on that order, to access References etc. By delaying the execution of `Start` you alter that order a bit.

So while the above works, I'd suggest to check a timer variable in `Update` or start a separate Coroutine in Start that runs later, but still letting `Start` return `void`.